# Eclipse CompareEditor detect save from different editor

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, editor, compare

I have a problem with Custom Eclipse Compare editor and file editor.

When saving from file editor, compare editor keeps dirty flag, file editor gets saved.
Same thing in revers works, compare and file editor both get marked as non-dirty files.

Is there a way for compare editor to detect the file change and remove dirty flag, it causes to open save dialog when trying to close compare editor even thoug file has been saved.

Have anyone had similar problems? Was solution found?

Comment: Are you just doing compare between two items in your Eclipse workspace from the UI?  Are you opening the compare editor programmatically?  If the latter, are you comparing *files* or *`IResource`s*?

Comment: the issue is with merge, compare editor is opened programmatically, im using IResource.

Comment: Hmm.  Can you post some code?  When I open the compare tool with `IResource`s it tracks dirty state with other editors.